# unable to implement Scheduled notification in flutter app

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications

I am really new to flutter app development. I am currently developing an app and i am using `youtube_api` and `youtube_video_player` packages to fetch the videos that i want my users to watch inside my app. Now I want to schedule a notification in my app so that which ever day users haven't watched their daily video they get notified.

I have tried to use `flutter_local_notifcation` Package in many different ways but can't get the notifications to funtion. The official documentation of the plugin has an example of 3000 lines of code which is not helping at all. I have watched code examples online but most of them are manually scheduling a notification by opening the app and then pressing a button to show the notifcation. I don't want that. I want to show the notification whichever day the user wasn't online. I also tried to use the awesome_notification package but couldn't set it up. I am not looking for the firebase_notifications because i don't want my users to be connected to internet in order to get the notification. Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.